# bash обрезает команды

Tags: linux, bash, консоль

При вводе длинный команды в консоль bash конец обрезает и считает как другую. Замучался уже, помогите

Comment: Мало информации, сделайте скриншот. Или дайте пример команды и опишите, что происходит.

Comment: есть длинная строка, например python3 sqlmap -u http://google.com --batch, последние слова, к примеру "--batch" он обрежет и будет считать другой командой, вместо того, чтобы добавить как параметр к первой

Comment: это не нормальное поведение, с которым кроме тебя скорей всего мало-кто сталкивался... опиши подробней свою среду, bash скорей всего тут не при чём... первое на что я бы кивал — какой-то кривой эмулятор терминала...

Comment: @АндрейЕвсюков если эта команда копируется с какого то сайта, где может неявно быть вставлен перевод строки, то это нормальное штатное поведение. Что делать? набирать команды ручками и обходить стороной сайты, которые такое практикуют (пусть даже в учебных целях).

Comment: в parrot security, через virtual box

Comment: А чё, нормальное такое секьюрити: *20 символов командной строки хватит каждому!*

Comment: Если руками набрать `echo очень-длинная-строка-символов-без-пробелов-и-табуляций` -- тоже обрезает посредине этой строки?

Answer (score 1):

Запиши команду в файл и запускай его. Пока пишешь заодно проверишь копипасту на лишние символы.

У меня такое получалось когда стрелкой вверх мотаю историю команд. Всё едет и ломается на длинных командах.